# Chebyshev inequality in a confidence region

Tags: probability, inequality

How can i establish that for each $$p \in [0,1] $$
if
$$X_{1},X_{2}...$$
are a coin runs to parameter p,
with the propability P to cover up the confidence region
$$R:=\left[\overline{X}_n-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{n}}, \overline{X}_n+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{n}}\right]$$
with Chebyshev inequality:
$$P((\overline{X}_n-EX) \ge c\sigma) \le \frac{1}{c^2}$$
not less than .95!

I start with

$$=> $$ $$P((\overline{X}_n-EX) \le c\sigma) \ge 1 - \frac{1}{c^2} \ge 0.95 $$

$$P(\overline{X}_n-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{n}}\le p \le \overline{X}_n+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{n}}) = 0.95$$

$$1-\frac{1}{c^2} = 0.95$$
$$c=2\sqrt{5}$$

From here I am stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.  Then, $E[S] = p$, 
$\text{var}(S) = \frac{p(1-p)}{n}$ and so by the Chebyshev inequality
$$P\biggr\{p - c\sqrt{\text{var}(S)} 
< S < p + c\sqrt{\text{var}(S)}\biggr\} \geq 1 - \frac{1}{c^2}$$
where the right side has value $0.95$ when $c = \sqrt{20}$.
But if $S$ *does* lie in the interval 
$$\left(p-\sqrt{20\cdot\text{var}(S)}, p+\sqrt{20\cdot\text{var}(S)}\right),$$
then $p$ must be in the interval 
$$\left(S - \sqrt{20\cdot\text{var}(S)}, S+\sqrt{20\cdot\text{var}(S)}\right),$$
that is, this is a $95\%$ *confidence interval* for the
unknown parameter $p$.
Since $\text{var}(S)$ has maximum value $\frac{1}{4n}$ when $p = \frac{1}{2}$,
we have that 
$$\left(S - \sqrt{20\cdot\text{var}(S)}, S+\sqrt{20\cdot\text{var}(S)}\right)
\subset \left(S - \sqrt{\frac{5}{n}}, S+\sqrt{\frac{5}{n}}\right),$$
and this superset is also a $95\%$ confidence interval
 for $p$.